# Change bottom view color of textfield on textbegin?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have created below UI for a login screen.I have added the UIView below the every text field & changed some color view.
[image]

To change view's some initial color i have created a custom class for UIView and added below code in it

```
import Foundation

class BottomView:UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let topRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width : 20, height: rect.size.height);
        // Fill the rectangle with grey
        UIColor.darkGray.setFill()
        UIRectFill(topRect)

    }
    }
```

Now i want when user tap or focus a textfield color of textfield should be changed as full color.To do that i used below code.

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == textFieldFirstName {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options:[.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
                self.bottomViewEmail.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }, completion:nil)

        }


    }
```

Now it changes the color of view but not from begining.it changes color of UIView from where there was already a color.

So please suggest me how can i do ?

Also i want when user move to password the color of previous textfield view should be same as it was initially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of some part of view from controller in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013997/how-to-change-color-of-some-part-of-view-from-controller-in-swift)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013997/how-to-change-color-of-some-part-of-view-from-controller-in-swift/47014843#47014843

Answer (score 0):

I think background color and Fill Color has some conflicts

Try This way only Use fill color  add it to sub class of your View

```
func fillColor(with color:UIColor,width:CGFloat) {

    let topRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width : width, height: self.bounds.height);

    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(topRect)

}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    self.fillColor(with: .gray, width: 20)

}
```

From  UIViewController class

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField == textFieldFirstName {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options:[.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            self.bottomViewEmail.fillColor(with: .green, width: self.bottomViewEmail.bounds.width)

    }


}
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: You are getting Same result ?

Comment: Second option would be use of `UIProgressView` and set progress accordingly much easier ?

Comment: for that i have to change the desgin i have designed in such a way to use only UIVIew

Comment: Can you suggest a better with view only?