# How to change color of some part of view from controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have created a custom UIView.I am making it's some part of color as other color using below code.

```
import Foundation

class BottomView:UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.fillColor(with: .gray, width: 20)
    }

    func fillColor(with color:UIColor,width:CGFloat) {

        let topRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width : width, height: self.bounds.height);
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(topRect)

    }

}
```

Now my view has some initial part of color as gray & rest of its color is different. Now from controller if i try to change it's color to green the it is not changed from start position. It's color changed after inital color.

Please let me know how i can completely set background color to green.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`setNeedsDisplay`** on your `bottom view` and redraw it when setting the `backgroundColor`.

> **setNeedsDisplay()**
>
> Marks the receiver’s entire bounds rectangle as needing to be redrawn.
>
> You can use this method or the setNeedsDisplay(_:) to notify the
>   system that your view’s contents need to be redrawn. This method makes
>   a note of the request and returns immediately. The view is not
>   actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle, at which point all
>   invalidated views are updated.

**Example:**

**1. `BottomView` `class`**

```
class BottomView:UIView
{
    var showGray = true

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        if showGray
        {
            self.fillColor(with: .gray, width: 20)
        }
    }

    func fillColor(with color:UIColor,width:CGFloat)
    {
        let topRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width : width, height: self.bounds.height);
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(topRect)
    }
}
```

**2. In your `UIViewController`**

```
self.bottomView.showGray = false
self.bottomView.setNeedsDisplay()
self.bottomView.backgroundColor = .green
```